# Regular Expression to select Filenames with exceptions

Tags: regex

How do I select all files in a directory with exception of few files like file-1.php, file-2.php and file-3.php ?

The exception file names can be anything like file-a.php, arbit-file-name.php or anything.jpg. Its not a sequential set of files like file-1 etc.

Comment: In what language / with what tools?  PowerGrep through COM with Delphi? Smalltalk over TC/IP routed through a private satellite system running on BASIC? ;-)  More details will help people answer your question thoroughly, rather than guessing in the dark.

Comment: I am looking to use this in a apache rewrite scheme.

Comment: Basically its a regular expression with negation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found it...

```
^(((?!file-a\.php)(?!random\.jpg)(?!whatever\.txt)).)*$
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
ls | grep -v '^(file\.php|random\.jpg|whatever\.txt)$'
```

EDIT: modified to allow arbitrary files.

Comment: The sequence that I gave in the question earlier was just a mere coincidence. I have updated the question accordingly.